# Struts2 form elements

Tags: struts2

Why is it that when I insert an element in between the s:textfield it gets placed on top?
Is there a way to fix that?
Thanks for helping on this.

```
<s:textfield label="First Name" required="true"/>
<s:textfield label="Last Name" required="true"/>
<s:text name="testing1">test1</s:text>
<s:textfield label="Address" required="false"/>
<s:textfield label="Email" required="true"/>
<s:text name="testing2">test2</s:text>
```

Order being displayed on browser:

```
test1
test2
First Name
Last Name
Address
Email
```

Comment: Ok even if I mix regular HTML like add a division between s:textfield components they still get placed on top.  What if I want to group different sections of the form by adding sort of like <fieldset><legend>.... in HTML? Will it be possible?

Comment: Do you use that in an <s:form> ? If so, try to put it in a regular form, as the <s:form> did strange things for me too.

Answer (score 1):

I guess my answer to this question comes too late, but I respond to this just for the record.

The reason why the text elements don't appear in between is because struts renders a table to display your input fields (and their labels). If you look at the HTML rendered by struts you will see one  tag for each textfield. If you insert any other component between these, struts will not know how to format these into the table of the form, resulting in the items being displayed before the start of the table.
To avoid this behavior you can set the "theme" attribute of the form to "simple". This will result in the fact that you will need to do all formatting by yourself.

Hope this helps.