# Struts2 form elements UI too rigid

Tags: forms, struts2, tags

i found a similar problem like this: 
 [Struts2 form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314296/struts2-form-elements)
but no answer is given until now. So here i post my difficulties with a vengeance.

I am using Struts2 with version 2.1.6. When I leave the input elements such as `<s:textfield>`, `<s:textarea>`, etc. of a `<s:form>` with the default theme, the elements are rendered as:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"><label for="firstname" class="label">Firstname:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"><label for="lastname" class="label">Lastname:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"/></td>
</tr>
```

Now if i want to add something, say an html label, between the two  elements, the result gets messed up as described in the related question above.

Another problem is: for the `<s:checkbox>` item, it is just not possible to add an extra title. For example, this tag

```
<s:checkbox id="defaultprinter" name="defaultprinter" key="lbl.defaultprinter"/>
```

is rendered as:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="right"></td>
    <td valign="top" align="left">
<input type="checkbox" name="defaultprinter" value="true" checked="checked" id="defaultprinter"/> <label for="defaultprinter" class="checkboxLabel">Default Printer</label> </td>
</tr>
```

By only setting the attributes of `<s:checkbox>`, i can't add any text to the first `<td>` shown above (here it is empty!).

I don't know if the above rigid UI problems can be solved or there is any workarounds somewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch your [theme](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/themes-and-templates.html). The extra (X)HTML tags are generated because of are using (probably) the *xhtml theme*. If you want to tweak it, you just use the *simple theme* and write the surrounding tags yourself. You can do that for the full form, or for some individual tags. You can even write your own themes, if you like.

Comment: thank you for the info. But is there any slick way to reuse the default theme while i can tune the UI to get the best of both worlds? I don't want to change all my existing pages (there are many such pages) by switching the theme.

Comment: themes are extensible. http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/extending-themes.html
But in your scenario, if you have used the default (xhtml) theme in many forms and want to make some individual tunings for a few inputs fields, I'd go the standard way: just change the theme (from default to "simple") for those fields.

Answer (score 0):

try using [Display](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/) tag or [JQuery](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) using both of these framewok can be used to create great (flexible) GUI